Interpreting capital market assumptions (geometric versus arithmetic returns)
I am going through capital market assumptions from Amundi(Link, Amundi). However, I am having trouble converting the displayed average annualised geometric return to the displayed average annualised arithmetic return. I am aware of the following approximation for converting the returns:
\begin{equation}
r_G \approx r_A - 0.5V(r_t).
\end{equation}
However, applying this formula I can not generally convert the "Average Annualised Arithmetic" return (10y) provided to the "Average Annualised Geometric" (10y) provided.
Am I doing something wrong or is this error in translation due to formula being an approximation?
Please find a screenshot below.


You might try a different approximation, usually more accurate than  $G\approx A-V/2$ which is : $1+G\approx (1+A)(1+V(1+A)^{-2})^{-1/2}$ See equation (A4) in https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2083915 . Maybe this is the formula thta Amundi is using.

If your results are close, then maybe the more accurate formula would help, but if not then the problem is likely something else. How far off are your results?
